# On a ngFor iteration, if a value is equal to a specific value do not list out the value using Angular4

Tags: angular, angular-forms

On a *ngFor iteration, if a value is equal to a specific value do not list out the value in the list using Angular4.

My template:

```
<div class="desktop-list btn-group-vertical show-cat">
    <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action cat-btn" *ngFor='let category of categories' (click)="getCatName($event)">{{category}}<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="mobile-select show-cat">
    <select class="mobile-select show-cat" [ngModel]="selectedCat" (ngModelChange)="change($event)" name="category" id="cat-column" placeholder="Select a Category">
      <option [ngValue]="category" class="cat-btn" *ngFor='let category of categories'>{{category}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Component getCategories function:

```
getCatgegories(masterProduct: number) {
  this.service.getCatgegories(masterProduct)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.categories = response.catList;
      this.categories.splice(0,0, 'Select a Category');
      this.masterName = response.name;
    });
}
```

I want to check if the category is = 'Select a Category' and if it returns true it will not display the item in the list of buttons. I feel like this should be an easy thing to accomplish but have had no luck in finding the solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a simple solution :

```
<div class="desktop-list btn-group-vertical show-cat">
    <ng-template ngFor let-category [ngForOf]="categories"> 
         <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action cat-btn" *ngIf="category !=='Select a Category'" (click)="getCatName($event)">{{category}}<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
          </button>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

hope it helps u :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a little confused on how to implement this solution. I need to show all categories except the category that = "Select a Category". I tried changing *ngIf="Category !== 'Select a Category'" but no dice.

Comment: It shows all my listed items as 'object object' as the text for the button

Comment: so the category is an object , i think u have to test if the name of the category (if it has a name.. i mean it's label .. you know already your object of what is composed ) does not equals 'select a category' like that : `*ngIf="Category.name !== 'Select a Category'"` , and it will work i guess

Comment: That's the weird part is that the array is a list of strings, not objects..

Comment: so weird , can you edit the post so we can see the `.ts` file to detect where is the problem exactly

Comment: Already ahead of you. if you need more info from component let me know. We will have to move to chat pretty soon if that's ok with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156374/discussion-between-med-ali-rachid-and-travis-michael-heller).

Comment: better to have the list pre-filtered, to save unnecessary iteration for not require items

Answer (score 0):

There must be better ways to handle this conceptually, but if all you want is to just not show the label for that particular case, then you can wrap your label in a `span` and hide it for that particular case.

```
<div class="desktop-list btn-group-vertical show-cat">
    <button class="list-group-item list-group-item-action cat-btn" *ngFor='let category of categories' (click)="getCatName($event)">
      <span *ngIf="category !== 'Select a Category'">{{category}}<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I was hoping not to go this route, do you have any other solutions? I ended up having the 'Select a Category' as a value form the array being iterated over cause I was unable to get the initial select value to show "Select a Category" since it is tied to ngModel. Basically, a poor hack cause I got tired of trying to get the initial value to show Select a Category.

Comment: You can detach the 'Select a Category' element from your array object `categories` (since it must be the only one without a value and then statically add that as the first `button` element in your list in the template, then use `ngFor` to show the remaining list of options after this static button tag.

Comment: So, I am hiding a div that list out my categories as buttons when it is in mobile view and showing the list that converts the categories into a select dropdown list. Hopefully, this explains my situation more. I added the 'Select a Category' item to the array so I can initially show the default option as 'Select a Category'. this works great but when I switch over to desktop view it shows the first button as Select a Category which I do not want.

Comment: What logic do you use to determine mobile and desktop views?

Comment: I am just using CSS media queries with display: none and block

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `[hidden]=" category === 'Select a Category'"`

Comment: I have already tried this solution and did not work. thanks though